# Azure api The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel. http client While calling some web api

Tags: c#, azure, ssl, dotnet-httpclient

Below code works fine on localhost but Getting the above error after deployed my api on microsoft azure .

My code is as follows:

```
public class UsersController : Controller   
{
    private readonly HttpClient _client;

    public UsersController()
    {
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
        _client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri("https://pincode.saratchandra.in/api") };
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    }

public JsonResult GetAddress(int pincode)
{
    var response     =_client.GetAsync("/pincode/125112").Result;

    //Here it throws an exception: got no response
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
    }

    return Json(ApiResult.Success(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Didn't get any response for above call just get the error

> The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

Comment: Did you find a fix for this? Experiencing the same issue.

Comment: No i was not able to find a fix for it.

Comment: Are you using Azure App Services or Azure Cloud Services for your API?

Answer (score 2):

We have recently had a number of similar issues with API's.

In our case these were resolved by changing the Security Protocol Type to TLS 1.2, like so:

```
  ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

This appears to be a result of the deprecation of SSL, and the recommendation of the adoption of TLS 1.2 by the PCI as of the middle of 2016. See [here](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/205043158-PCI-3-1-and-TLS-1-2) for more

EDIT:

This works for me:

```
 class Program
    {
        private static HttpClient _client;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
            _client = new HttpClient ();
            _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            var response = _client.GetAsync("https://pincode.saratchandra.in/api/pincode/125112").Result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: i have already tried all the options for SecurityProtocol none of them not work for me  -;)

Comment: For me too thats works fine on local server and windows server but on azure it doesn't work

Comment: You are not alone. There's a lengthy thread https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/ca6372be-3169-4fb5-870f-bfbea605faf6/azure-webapp-webjob-exception-could-not-create-ssltls-secure-channel?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview, but no resolution

Answer (score 0):

We have been solving the same problem just today, and all you need to do is to increase the runtime version of .NET

**4.5.2 didn't work** for us with the above problem, while **4.6.1 was OK**

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1"/>
```

If you need to keep the .NET version, then set

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing issue with a new function app deployment, I was getting the same error message -

> The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

I was using self hosted agent but when I used `Microsoft hosted agent` for deployment it worked. The problem was due to some missing TLS 1.2 settings and Configuring strong cryptography. I had to add below keys in the registry and of course a machine restart afterwards.

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NETFramework\v2.0.50727]
"SystemDefaultTlsVersions" = dword:00000001
"SchUseStrongCrypto" = dword:00000001
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
"SystemDefaultTlsVersions" = dword:00000001
"SchUseStrongCrypto" = dword:00000001
```

And it worked as a charm afterwards. [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/core/plan-design/security/enable-tls-1-2-client)